# Anticommutation relation different specie/type of fermion

Tags: quantum-field-theory, fermions, anticommutator

Suppose we have two distinct fermions, say $X$ is Dirac, $Y$ is Majorana, part of different irreps of some Gauge group (e.g. SM). Alternatively, consider a  lepton $l=l_L+l_R$ and a Majorana neutrino $N=N_L+N_R=N^c$. Assume $X \in \{X_1,\ldots,X_m\}$, $Y\in \{Y_1,\ldots,Y_n\}$ ie each fermion has a number of flavours.

Let $a(X)^\dagger |0 \rangle =|X \rangle $ denote the creation operator in the occupation number basis, $a(X,\mathbf{p})^\dagger |0\rangle =|X(\mathbf{p})\rangle$ be the creation operator in the momentum basis. Of course given arbitrary bases for Hilbert space, we can always relate them via

\begin{equation}
a_{\tilde{\alpha}}^\dagger = \sum_\alpha \langle \alpha|\tilde{\alpha}\rangle \,a_\alpha^\dagger.
\end{equation}

In our case, $\alpha \equiv n_\alpha$, the occupation number, whereas $\tilde{\alpha}\equiv \mathbf{p}$, the three momentum. We write then the related bases for Fock space $\mathcal{F} = \mathcal{H}_0 \oplus \mathcal{H}_1 \oplus\ldots $ as

\begin{equation}
|n_1,n_2,\ldots n_\alpha\rangle_{\text{occ. basis}} = \frac{(a(\phi_1)^\dagger)^n}{\sqrt{n_1!}} \ldots \frac{(a(\phi_\alpha)^\dagger)^n}{\sqrt{n_\alpha!}} |0\rangle
\end{equation}
Where $\phi$ represent the particle fields each operator creates, $n_i \in \mathbb{N_0}$ for bosons, $\{0,1\}$ for fermions.

Likewise, we write the momentum basis as

\begin{equation}
|\phi_1(\mathbf{p}_1),\ldots, \phi_\alpha (\mathbf{p}_\alpha)\rangle_{\text{mom. basis}} = a(\phi_1,\mathbf{p}_1)^\dagger \ldots a(\phi_\alpha,\mathbf{p}_\alpha)^\dagger |0\rangle
\end{equation}

Equivalently the relativistic momentum vector is 
\begin{equation}
|\phi_1({p}_1),\ldots, \phi_\alpha ({p}_\alpha)\rangle_{\text{mom. basis}} = \sqrt{2E_{\mathbf{p}_1}\ldots E_{\mathbf{p}_\alpha}} \,a(\phi_1,\mathbf{p}_1)^\dagger \ldots a(\phi_\alpha,\mathbf{p}_\alpha)^\dagger |0\rangle
\end{equation}
I have several questions with this setup:

Suppose I consider the anti/commutations for $\xi = \pm 1$ and $[a(X_i),a(Y_j)]_{\xi} = a(X_i)a(Y_j) -\xi a(Y_j)a(X_i) \in \mathbb{C}$
\begin{equation}
[a(X_i),a(Y_j)]_{\xi} \in \mathbb{C}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
[a(X_i),a(Y_j)^\dagger]_{\xi} \in \mathbb{C}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
[a(X_i)\dagger,a(Y_j)^\dagger]_{\xi} \in \mathbb{C}
\end{equation}

Firstly, why do we need to take the antifermionic relation? By Pauli exclusion, if I take two of the same specie, they must vanish, for example

\begin{equation}
|X_i,X_j\rangle = -|X_j,X_i\rangle
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
|Y_i,Y_j\rangle = -|Y_j,Y_i\rangle
\end{equation}

But if I take two different species, then nothing should stop us from implementing the commutation between them?, e.g.
\begin{equation}
|X_i,Y_j\rangle = +|Y_j,X_i\rangle
\end{equation}

Of course one key feature of the fermion anticommutation relation is to prevent the unboundedness of the free Hamiltonian:

\begin{equation}
[H^{(0)}_{X_i},a(X_i,\mathbf{p})]= - E_{X_i,\mathbf{p}}\, a(X_i,\mathbf{p})
\end{equation}

As well as causality outside the light cone. But this doesn't need to be protected between two different species? It is often quoted that we still impose the anticommutation relation in the relativistic limit, and can arbitrarily choose commutators/anticommutators in the non-relativsitic case, though this does not appear obvious to me. Also, the idea that we must impose a superalgebra does not match the fact creating $X_i$ then $Y_j$, should be order independent (as a counter example, creating an electron and muon field, the only distinguishing feature is mass, ie they belong to the same class of fermion, crucially with the same quantum numbers and thus we must anticommute them. Now create a Majorana neutrino state, with different quantum numbers to the electron; surely they should lie in a free part of Hilbert space away from the electron state, like a tensor product, so these operators should commute? )

Secondly, if we justify somehow the anticommutation relation between different species, then in the case of Majorana neutrinos, does this still also hold, that two different types of fermions must anticommute?